# Player movement is frame dependant even with Time.deltaTime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, frame-rate

I'm trying to port my friend's Scratch game to Unity for fun, but the code for deceleration is causing the player to speed up and slow down depending on the framerate. The maximum X velocity should be 6.75, which it is at 30 fps, (scratch's usual framerate), but when the FPS changes his speed varies up to ~7.5.
Code (Unfinished):

```
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector2 Velocity, WallJumpForce;
    public float Acceleration, Decceleration;
    public float Gravity, JumpForce;
    public int TargetFPS;

    void Update()
    {
        Velocity.y -= Gravity;
        if(Input.GetKey("right") || Input.GetKey("d"))
        Velocity.x += Acceleration * SDT();
        if(Input.GetKey("left") || Input.GetKey("a"))
        Velocity.x -= Acceleration * SDT();
        Velocity.x -= Velocity.x*(1-Decceleration) * SDT();
        Move(Velocity.x, 0);
        Debug.Log(1 / Time.deltaTime + ", " + SDT());
        Application.targetFrameRate = TargetFPS;
    }

    void Move(float x, float y) //Converts Scratch Units to Unity Units
    {
        transform.position += new Vector3(x, y, 0) * 1.2f * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    
    float SDT() //Basically allows Scratch variables designed for 30fps work in unity
    {
        return 30 * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

I've discovered that changing `Velocity.x *= Decceleration * SDT();`
to
`Velocity.x -= Velocity.x*(1-Decceleration) * SDT();` helps, but does not fix the problem.
For reference, this is the game I'm porting.
https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/590825095

Comment: Note that movement logic should not be tied to the framerate unless you ensure that a fixed framerate is used, but even then it's not a good idea. The general idea is that you need to have an underlying game model that is completely independent and separate from the graphical display, and the act of drawing a frame is simply representing the current state of the model, this prevents the game from feeling jittery or causing issues like you are experiencing when the logic is fixed to the framerate.

Comment: Why are you setting `Application.targetFrameRate` anyway?   Unless you have gotten to the point in the game where users select a framerate from Options you shouldn't be fiddling with it.  Just let Unity max out.

Comment: MickeyD It’s just for testing since the code works fine at 30 fps

Comment: Please dont forget to select an answer

Answer (score 3):

Do yourself a favor and verify your units every single time you write a physics equation. In this case verifying your units will solve the problem.

Velocity has units of distance/time and gravity has units of distance/(time^2).

So lets examine the units on this line:

```
 Velocity.y -= Gravity;
```

You are saying distance/time -= distance/(time^2). 
Those units don't work!

Clearly you will have to multiply `Gravity` by some amount of time to get a change in velocity. For that we have Δt, the amount of time that has passed since the last frame:

```
Velocity.y -= Gravity * Time.deltaTime;
```

Now the units are distance/time -= distance/(time^2)*time. That makes a whole lot more sense. **Do that for all your physics equations and your problem will be solved.**

Comment: You’re right I do need to fix the Gravity calculations but the issue is with decceleration

Comment: @GBAM13 You have missed the point of my answer. I used gravity as an example, but you need to do unit analysis on ALL of your physics equations. Do your units here check out?  `Velocity.x -= Velocity.x*(1-Decceleration) * SDT();` No. They don't.

Comment: SDT() is just 30 * Time.deltaTime

Comment: @GBAM13 I'm aware of that. `Velocity.x` is distance/time. `1` is unitless. `Deceleration` is distance/time^2. Does distance/time - distance/time*(unitless - distance/time^2)*time make any sense to you?

Comment: @GBAM13 what you want is `Velocity.x -= Deceleration * SDT();`

Comment: Odds are you are trying to simulate air drag. For that you will need to define some relationship between speed and deceleration. A simple way to do this is to define `Drag` with units of acceleration/speed (how much do I slow down based on a given speed). Acceleration/speed simplifies to 1/time. Now your equation becomes: 
`var deceleration = Velocity.x * Drag;// distance/time^2` `Velocity.x -= deceleration * SDT(); // distance/time`